# How can I decrypt a bitlocker drive after startup automatically without encrypting the Windows drive?

Tags: windows, disk-encryption, bitlocker

I want to startup my Windows and then see a dialog box (or a commandline window) that prompts me for the drive password to decrypt it automatically after bootup.

I tried to make a .bat "script" ([related question](https://superuser.com/questions/463303/scripting-bitlocker-decryption-of-a-local-hard-drive)) but it just didn't work while I was able to decrypt the drive with the same commands I by hand in the commandline.

Comment: Even though this questions overlaps with the related question; I think it's useful to have this one because a lot of people might search with this phrasing

Comment: "it just didn't work" - Why, any errors?

Comment: I'm stupid - I forget the pause at the end. But now I need to find a way to make it start as administrator from startup

Comment: Have you seen [these](http://superuser.com/questions/183011/auto-start-a-program-and-run-under-other-account-on-user-logon) [questions](http://superuser.com/questions/418136/how-to-run-an-exe-on-boot-and-keep-it-running-regardless-of-who-logs-in-on-wind) already?

Answer (score 3):

**My current (unpolished barebone) solution:**

.bat file with

```
@echo off
manage-bde G: -unlock -password
pause
```

Put that in the task manager; trigger *at logon*. It has to [run as administrator (highest voted answer works like a charm)](https://superuser.com/questions/71190/running-bat-file-at-startup-as-administrator-in-windows-7). Has one big flaw though at the moment: When I enter a wrong password I don't get another prompt but "*press any key to continue...*"